# Differences between com.mongodb.client.MongoClient and com.mongodb.MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm a bit new in MongoDB and I got confused with MongoClient classes as there are two in different packages (`com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` and `com.mongodb.MongoClient`). And what I have seen is that they have more or less the same purpose but I could be wrong.

What are the differences between both classes? Is one of them recommended over the other?

Comment: From the [MongoDB Java Driver 3.12 (reference)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/getting-started/quick-start/) documentation, `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();` is the way to create a `MongoClient` object, and the _legacy way_ is the `com.mongodb.MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();`. That indicates `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` is the one you can consider using. I guess it depends upon the version of the driver software you are using. Prior to driver version 3.7 there is only one option: `com.mongodb.MongoClient`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient.create()` (as of 3.7 or later), legacy api `com.mongodb.MongoClient()` is deprecated.

A `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` instance represents a pool of connections to the database; you will only need one instance of class MongoClient even with multiple threads.

Reference : http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.12/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/

`com.mongodb.client.MongoClient` is added since 3.7 release use below code to get instance with new API:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create()
```

Comment: Is this 3.7 mongoDB version or the driver version ?